# c++ template nested typename

Tags: c++, templates, nested

One of the motivations behind requiring C++ programmers to put the typename keyword before accessing
a type nested inside a templatized type was to prevent ambiguity in templates. For example, consider
the following code, which assumes the existence of a template type called MyTemplate:

```
template <typename T> void MyFunction(const T& elem)
{
    int itr;
    while(true)
    {
        typename MyTemplate<T>::Inner * itr;
    }
}
```

Consider the line

```
        typename MyTemplate<T>::Inner * itr.
```

Since we have the typename
keyword here, the compiler understands that we're declaring a pointer of type MyTemplate::Inner*
called itr. If we don't put the

`typename`

keyword in here, C++ will think that
   `MyTemplate<T>::Inner`  is a class constant rather than a type. What will the statement
    `MyTemplate<T>::Inner * itr`
mean in this case? Does the difference between these two cases help explain why the typename keyword is necessary?

Comment: Why does `typename` inside a loop make any sense?  What are you doing with `itr` here other than declaring it? This code needs a bit more context to make sense.

Comment: This question is exercise from my book.I think this explanation from my book will clarify: